# Facebook sharing not scraping url correctly in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, meta-tags, facebook-share

I am trying to share on facebook but didn't get meta data. Also i have try in facebook debug tool but didn't get meta data.

facebook debug tool url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I have already added meta data. Bellow meta data and url.

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Afrocamgist" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.afrocamgist.com/public/campus_post/Screenshot_20180815-132503.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Good morning famz!" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.afrocamgist.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Afrocamgist" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="300434940539027" />
```

URL : https://www.afrocamgist.com/post/single/434

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve issue, Actually problem with protected page. My page is open after user login. 
I have a remove permission and publish to solve my issue.

Thanks.